# Impossible to create correlated variables from this correlation matrix?

Tags: r, correlation

I would like to generate correlated variables specified by a correlation matrix.

First I generate the correlation matrix:

```
require(psych)
require(Matrix)

cor.table <- matrix( sample( c(0.9,-0.9) , 2500 , prob = c( 0.8 , 0.2 ) , repl = TRUE ) , 50 , 50 )
k=1
while (k<=length(cor.table[1,])){
    cor.table[1,k]<-0.55
    k=k+1
    }
k=1
while (k<=length(cor.table[,1])){
    cor.table[k,1]<-0.55
    k=k+1
    }   
ind<-lower.tri(cor.table)
cor.table[ind]<-t(cor.table)[ind]
diag(cor.table) <- 1
```

This correlation matrix is not consistent, therefore, eigenvalue decomposition is impossible.
TO make it consistent I use nearPD:

```
c<-nearPD(cor.table)
```

Once this is done I generate the correlated variables:

```
fit<-principal(c, nfactors=50,rotate="none")
fit$loadings
loadings<-matrix(fit$loadings[1:50, 1:50],nrow=50,ncol=50,byrow=F)
loadings

cases <- t(replicate(50, rnorm(10)) ) 
multivar <- loadings %*% cases
T_multivar <- t(multivar)
var<-as.data.frame(T_multivar)
cor(var)
```

However the resulting correlations are far from anything that I specified initially.

Is it not possible to create such correlations or am I doing something wrong?

`UPDATE` from Greg Snow's comment it became clear that the problem is that my initial correlation matrix is unreasonable.

The question then is how can I make the matrix reasonable. The goal is:

1. each of the 49 variables should correlate >.5 with the first variable.
2. ~40 of the variables should have a high >.8 correlation with each other
3. the remaining ~9 variables should have a low or negative correlation with each other.

Is this whole requirement impossible ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `mvrnorm` function from the MASS package rather than trying to construct the variables yourself.

**Edit

Here is a matrix that is positive definite (so it works as a correlation matrix) and comes close to your criteria, you can tweak the values from there (all the Eigen values need to be positive, so you can see how changing a number affects things):

```
cor.mat <- matrix(0.2,nrow=50, ncol=50)
cor.mat[1,] <- cor.mat[,1] <- 0.55
cor.mat[2:41,2:41] <- 0.9
cor.mat[42:50, 42:50] <- 0.25
diag(cor.mat) <- 1

eigen(cor.mat)$values
```

Comment: rmvnorm(n=4, mean=c(rep(0,50)),cor.table, method="svd") this still doesn't produce anything near the original correlation matrix

Comment: @user1723765, with only 4 observations the sample correlations will be highly variable.  What result do you get with a sample size of say 1,000?  How are you computing the correlation and comparing? and did you try `mvrnorm` with `empirical=TRUE`?

Comment: please see my edit. the correlations are still far away from the desired ones. I think nearPD already distorts the whole thing. is it not possible to create correlated variables from my initial matrix?

Comment: Your initial table is not reasonable as a correlation matrix, for example variables 2 and 3 both have a 0.9 correlation with variable 4, but are expected to have a -0.9 correlation with each other, so the `nearPD` function needs to change the values quite a bit to get something reasonable.  Also note that `nearPD` computes covariances by default, if you have it compute correlations, pass that to `mvrnorm` and then compare the correlation of the result to the `c` matrix you should see similar values.

Comment: ok, so the problem is that the initial correlation matrix is unreasonable. Now I understand. Please see my edit.

Comment: @user1723765, I have edited my answer to show a possible correlation matrix to start with.

Comment: perfect! this is exactly what I'm looking for. the only thing: is there a way to mix it up a little so that not only the last few variables have a low correlation while the rest have a high one but to make the high and low correlations more mixed in the matrix?

Comment: @user1984076, you could generate a small to moderate sized dataset from the starting correlation matrix (with `empirical=FALSE`), then compute the correlation matrix for that data and use that as your new correlation matrix, possibly repeating the process a couple more times.  That will give you some randomness, but the same general pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Some numerical experimentation based on your specifications above suggests that the generated matrix will *never* (what never? well, hardly ever ...) be positive definite, but it also doesn't look far from PD with these values (making `lcor` below negative will almost certainly make things worse ...)

```
rmat <- function(n=49,nhcor=40,hcor=0.8,lcor=0) {
    m <- matrix(lcor,n,n)  ## fill matrix with 'lcor'
    ## select high-cor variables
    hcorpos <- sample(n,size=nhcor,replace=FALSE)
    ## make all of these highly correlated
    m[hcorpos,hcorpos] <- hcor                
    ## compute min real part of eigenvalues
    min(Re(eigen(m,only.values=TRUE)$values))
}
set.seed(101)
r <- replicate(1000,rmat())
## NEVER pos definite
max(r)
## [1] -1.069413e-15
par(las=1,bty="l")
png("eighist.png")
hist(log10(abs(r)),breaks=50,col="gray",main="")
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. so this suggests that my initial matrix won't work. is there a way to find something similar that can work? see the last few lines of my post where I specify what I'm looking for. exact correlation values are not necessary only the 3 conditions specified should be fulfilled.

Comment: try it out for yourself ... I wrote the function so that it would be easy to tweak.  I would suggest modifying `lcor` so it's a little bit positive ...